# Resizing BayerRG8 image using PySpin(FLIR) changes it to grayscale

Tags: python, numpy, flir, pyspin, spinnaker-cam

I am using a FLIR Blackfly S BFS-PGE-31S4C to collect video and writing the video with python, using the PySpin package. I wanted to add a real time video preview so I could see what was being recorded and wanted to downsize the image so I could easily see the entire frame on my screen. Below is my current code:

```
im = cam.GetNextImage(PySpin.EVENT_TIMEOUT_INFINITE if wait else PySpin.EVENT_TIMEOUT_NONE)
im = im.GetNDArray()
resize_factor = 2

cv2.imshow("test1",cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_RG2RGB))
cv2.waitKey(0)

im = im[::resize_factor,::resize_factor]

cv2.imshow("test2",cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_RG2RGB))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The cameras record in Bayer RG8 format. PySpin has a .GetNDArray() method which converts the image to numpy array (still in the bayer RG8 format I believe because the values are `uint8`). When I look at the type `(type(im),type(im[0]),type(im[0][0]))` of the numpy array prior to resizing it is a `2D numpy.ndarray` containing `numpy.uint8` values, and this is the same after I resize the image. When I show the first image (before conversion), it is in color. When I show the second, resized image, it is grayscale and just ignores the cv2.cvtColor() call.

I think it may have something to do with the BayerRG8 format of the original image but not sure why resizing it affects it in this way as I do not have a good knowledge of that image format. Any advice on my problem or suggestions to improve the question are appreciated!

Comment: It is very tricky to resize a Bayer image.  Remember that the color components are interleaved (R,G.R.G and then G,B,G,B).  Your simple decimation is not going to honor the pixel values.  If you decimate by 2, you will end up just with the R plane.  You should use an image library to do the resize, rather than just decimation, and probably should convert to RGB first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very tricky to resize a Bayer image.  Remember that the color components are interleaved:

```
R G R G R G ...
G B G B G B ...
R G R G R G ...
```

Your simple decimation is not going to honor the pixel values.  If you decimate by 2, you will end up just with the R plane.  You should use an image library to do the resize, rather than just decimation, and probably should convert to RGB first.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I saw similar behavior (of changing to grayscale) when using OpenCV (i.e. cv2.resize(im,None,fx=0.5,fy=0.5,interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)). I suppose it fell victim to the same issue, especially with the interpolation? I will try converting to RGB first and see how that goes.